# Connecting Apache Cassandra to DataGrip

Tags: docker, cassandra, containers, datagrip

After I pull the image for Cassandra and run a container and create the database, I want to add its data source on DataGrip to manage the database from there. When I run the container I made it listen too the ports `9842`. By typing the commands:

- `docker pull cassandra`
- `docker run -d cassandra-node -p 9842:9842`
- `docker exec -it cassandra-node bash`

The host is `localhost` and I try to access the database with `jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9842` URL.

I tried to connect, but every time I get the error:

`All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9842 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [localhost/127.0.0.1:9842] Channel has been closed)).`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run your container on localhost and did not change Cassandra's configuration Cassandra will start on port 9042 in the container.
You should change your docker run command to

> docker run -d cassandra-node -p 9842:9042

This binds port 9042 of the container to port 9842 on the host machine.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide a lot of information in terms of how you configured the connection to Cassandra in DataGrip but the error you posted indicates that either:

- your nodes are not running on `localhost`, or
- Cassandra is not listening for clients on port `9842`.

You need to connect to the address that Cassandra is listening for CQL clients, i.e. the IP configured in `rpc_address`. Also, the default CQL port is `9042`.

Finally, you also need to ensure that there is network connectivity between DataGrip and the nodes. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, I changed the port to the default one and it worked. I still don't understand why it doesn't work with another port than the default one.